# Android : DLNA compliant devices

Tags: android, dlna

I need to find the list of DLNA compliant devices in my network from my Android application.

I'm using the API's from org.cybergarage.

They're available in Java, I want to make them Android capable i.e. Porting APis

Any help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Cling](http://4thline.org/projects/cling/) has source code already ported for android and ready to use. You can implement a discovery with in mins.

Moreover, it comes with very good tutorials.